# ASP MVC 4 managing object state in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

I am new to MVC and am having a conceptual problem with state and object persistence and hope someone can put my thoughts in order.

I have a remote webservice which provides methods to manage orders.  An order consists of a header and Lines as you would expect.  Lines can have additional requirements.

I have my domain objects created (using xsd2code from the webservice schema), the webservice calls and object serialization all working fine.  I've build the DAL/BLL layers and it's all working - tested using a WinForms testbed app front-end.

I have view model objects mapped from the domain objects using Automapper.  As the order is returned from a single webservice method complete with lines etc I have an OrderViewModel as follows

```
    public class OrderViewModel
{
    public OrderHeaderViewModel OrderHeader { set; get; }
    public List<OrderLineViewModel> OrderLines { set; get; }
    public List<OrderLineAdditionalViewModel> OrderLineAdditional { set; get; }
    public List<OrderJustificationViewModel> OrderJustifications { set; get; }

}
```

Firstly I'm wondering if I should dispense with the OrderViewModel as if I pass this as a model to a view I'm passing far more data than I need.  Views only need OrderHeader or OrderLines etc - not the entire order.

Now my conceptual problem is in the controllers and the views and object persistence.

My Order controller has a Detail Action which performs the load of the order from the webservice and maps the Domain object to the OrderViewModel object.

```
    public ActionResult Details(string orderNumber)
    {

        OrderViewModel viewModel = new OrderViewModel();
        var order = WebServiceAccess.LoadOrderByOrderNumber(orderNumber,"OBOS_WS");

        viewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BusinessEntities.Order, ViewModels.OrderViewModel>(order);

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

But the Order/Details.cshtml just has the page layout and a call to two partial pages for the header and the lines (I swap the Headerview for a HeaderEdit using Ajax, same for the LinesView)

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("DetailsHeaderViewPartial", Model);}
@{ Html.RenderPartial("DetailsLinesViewPartial", Model);}
```

At the moment I'm passing the model into the main Details container page, then into the RenderPartials, However I don't think that the model should be passed to the main Detail page, as it doesn't need it - the model is only needed in the DetailsHeaderViewPartial, DetailsLinesViewPartial so I'd be better off using @RenderAction here instead and passing the model into the Header/Lines views instead.

However, The Order is retrieved from the webservice in the ActionResult Details() how can I make the retrieved OrderViewModel object available in the ActionResult HeaderDetails() / LineDetails() methods of the controller to pass as the model in return PartialView(...,model) ?

Should I use a User Session to store the Order ViewModel so it can be used across actions in the controller.

Moving on from this stage the user will be able to maintain the order (add/remove lines - edit the header etc).  As the webservice call to save the order could take a few seconds to complete I'd rather only call the save method when the user has finished with the order.  I therefore would like to persist the in-progress order locally somewhere whilst it's being worked on.  User session ?

Many thanks for any advice.  Once I've got my head around state management for the ViewModels I'll be able to stop reading a million Blog posts and actually write this thing !

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a few questions here so I will try to address them all the best I can.

1) Dispensing with the view model : I would say no. The view model represents the data that you need in order to populate your view. It seems like you are using the view model as an identical container to the domain model object. So you are asking if you should dispense with it and just pass the domain model to the view while your original concern is that you are passing along more data then you really need as is?

Rather then dispensing with the view model, I would revisit your properties on your view model. Only use properties that you need and create the mapping logic (either with automapper or on your own) for taking the complex domain object and populating the properties on the view model.

summation: build the view model to be only things that the view needs and write mapping logic to populate that view model.

2) This is just a statement of best practice before I breakdown your specific scenario.

You describe your architecture as having a BLL and DAL. If that is the case then you should not be persisting any objects from your controller. The controller should not have any knowledge of the database even existing and the objects used in the controller should have no idea of how to persist themselves. The objects that are going between your controller and the web service should strictly be Data Transfer Objects (DTO's). If you are unfamiliar with what constitutes a DTO then I highly suggest that you do some research and try to build them into your solution. It will help you conceptually see the difference between view model objects, domain objects and data transfer objects.

3) I would not try to store an order object in the session. I would re-analyze how you are breaking up the partial views within the view so that you can call actions with the ordersviewmodel being the parameter in a way that you need. It sounds like you are needlessly breaking up views into partial views.

4) You should not be concerned with state management for the view model object. Your view (which can be comprised of many partial views) is filled based on properties provided by the view model. The user can make changes using the UI you have developed. Since you express the desire to only save once they are finished making all changes to optimize calls to the web service, you just need to repopulate the fields of the view model upon clicking submit. Now you have a "state" for orderviewmodel that represents the users changes. You can send this object to the web service after converting back to a DTO (if you do what I said above) or by mapping it to the domain object.

1 final note. You are using automapper to map your domain to the view model. I am assuming that your view model is too complex and includes things that you don't need because you built your view model to emulate the domain object so that automapper could map by naming convention. Automapper has an api for doing complex (custom) mappings that fall outside of standard same name properties. Don't let automapper constrain you to building your view models a certain way.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for reply.  With regards to the viewmodel, I wasn't intending to dispense with it entirely sorry - just split it out of an OrderViewModel container (which includes header and lines) into seperate viewmodels - so I can pass OrderHeaderViewModel to the header partial rather than passing the entire Order model.

The reason for the partial views was to present the order in a single page, but to allow editing of header or lines by swapping out the partial views with edit views representing the same data using Ajax to switch view. So load entire order then paint using partials.